# How can I show all colors which are found in the product table that are also in the @color table

Tags: t-sql

I am doing the MVA T-SQL beginner course and I am spending way too long on this particular lab problem:

> *Create a table variable and populate it with a list of distinct
>   colors from the SalesLT.Product table. Then use the table variable to
>   filter a query that returns the product ID, name, and color from the
>   SalesLT.Product table so that only products with a color listed in the
>   table variable are returned.*

My query is:

```
DECLARE @colors table
(color varchar(55))

INSERT INTO @colors
SELECT DISTINCT color FROM saleslt.Product

SELECT p.productID, p.name, p.color
FROM saleslt.product AS p
WHERE color=@color;
```

I get the error message must declare the scalar variable "@color". Does this mean I can only assign one color to @colors?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Will make sure I do that in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a table into the `WHERE` clause, because that doesn't make any sense.  One approach here would be to just join your two tables together:

```
SELECT
    p.productID,
    p.name,
    p.color
FROM saleslt.product p
INNER JOIN @colors c
    ON p.color = c.color
```

The basic idea behind the join is that only product records having a color which appears in your `@color` table would be retained in the result set.

You could also have phrased this query using `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    p.productID,
    p.name,
    p.color
FROM saleslt.product p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @colors c WHERE p.color = c.color)
```